# Cannot create '"master" branch in Github to replace "Master" branch

Tags: git, github

I am taking over a project and I realised that they have been using a "Master" branch instead of a "master" branch. From what I read up, the branches are case-sensitive, and hence they are not the same. Therefore, I tried to create a rename the "Master" branch to "master", but everytime it tells me "master" branch already exists, but I am quite sure it is not there. (I tried doing git branch -M master)

Comment: You're likely using Windows or MacOS with a case insentitive file system. You need to rename to another name first (`tmpMaster` or something like that) and then to `master`, because.

Comment: I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux...I thought that would have been fine. Let me try your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: if you're working on an NTFS file system, then you'll still run into the same issues, even within WSL.

Comment: This worked, thank you!